# Разбор строки по шаблону (не регулярки)

Tags: php, парсер

Хочется странного.

Есть очень большой массив строк. Все эти строки хорошо ложатся под некий набор шаблонов.

```
"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago)",
"Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]",
"HP-UX bi2 B.11.31 U ia64 3768995465 unlimited-user license",
"Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]",
"SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)",
"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)",
"HP-UX cfb B.11.31 U ia64 3919763569 unlimited-user license",
"Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]",
"SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)",
"Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]",
"SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)",
"HP-UX mappn B.11.31 U ia64 1709713642 unlimited-user license",
"HP-UX appn B.11.31 U ia64 1709713642 unlimited-user license",
"SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)",
"Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]",
.....
```

То есть, например, Red Hat описывается таким шаблоном (на примере printf)

```
$vendor      = "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server";
$version     = 6;
$patchLevel  = 0;
$versionName = "Santiago";

printf("%s release %d.%d (%s)", $vendor, $version, $patchLevel, $versionName);
```

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0 (Santiago)

Так вот, хочется этакий printf наоборот, чтобы по шаблону разобрать строку на части.

Понятно, что это легко делается с помощью регулярок, но список реально очень большой и в целом потянет за собой довольно много обвязки для анализа результата.

Есть мысли, куда можно посмотреть?

Comment: Если попроще и побыстрее, то можно попробовать глянуть в сторону функции `sscanf`. Иначе можно заморочиться и написать парсер на конечных автоматах, синтаксический анализатор лол! Если шаблон точно простой и известный, то регулярки тут - самое оно. Не вижу пока причин отказываться от них.

Comment: Вот про sscanf оформите ответом плиз, ибо то, что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С некоторыми оговорками подходит функция [sscanf](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sscanf.php)

Так как ключ `s` останавливает чтение на любом пробельном символе (и только на нем!), то, например, для такой строки

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
```

вот такой шаблон не подойдет:

```
%s %s [%s %s]
```

Потому как последний `%s` захватит все символы до конца строки, включая закрывающую квадратную скобку. Придется принудительно разбивать строку на числа и молиться, чтобы в минорные версии не закралась буква. Вот так будет работать:

```
%s %s [%s %i.%i.%i]
```

А вот такую строку разобрать, без доработки напильником, в принципе не получится:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601a]
```